# Something weird going on with this question

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer, sock-puppets

I was browsing the New answers to Old Questions 10k queue, and came across an odd, new answer, so I went to the question:

[Wake app at regular intervals while using UIBackgroundModes=location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9384306/237838)

While viewing [this non-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15222925/237838), and seeing it inexplicably get up-voted, I saw [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15222856/237838) get posted, and up-voted.

They have each been up-voted again while I type this, despite them clearly being simple rants. I also see no evidence whatsoever about what the rants say.

Clearly, something strange is going on here. I'd flag, but I'm out of 'Notify Moderator' flags, and I'm also scratching my head and wanting to know if I'm not going out of it!

One odd thing; one of the new users [Agent Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997115/agent-smith?tab=summary) has only answered questions by Zee, aside from the recent thing. Seems odd for them to have gotten such an attachment to him... ;)

And then, odd, sudden voting patterns on [Zee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210962/zee?tab=reputation)

Comment: So... you couldn't wait a week to find out, could you? ;P

Comment: @Yannis haha! I'll have to remember to bookmark some profiles so I can take a peek later ;)

Comment: OK, what am I missing - what happens in a week?

Comment: @Vicky Andrew is a candidate in the [moderator election](http://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1), and he's currently leading the primary vote.

Comment: The flag queue comes first.  Don't fool yourself into thinking that you'll have all this time for bookmarked profiles blah blah blah.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you both. Moderator election! I should probably vote.

Comment: @casperOne hehe; I know, you are right! Besides, though; you know I'm anxious to start digging into that!

Comment: You are out of flags...that seems shocking! :)  What are the mods going to do if you are not flagging thousands of items?!?

Comment: @bluefeet You get fifty flags a day, tops.

Comment: @casperOne I know. I just don't know how anyone could catch up to Andrew's 9k+ flags.  I guess I better get back to flagging.

Comment: @bluefeet If I had to guess, I'd say I'm not the most prolific flagger. Though certainly I'd be up there! And I would also say that volume isn't as important as my stats might seem to suggest I would think they are. Or something like that!

Comment: @AndrewBarber I thought I had a lot of flags until I saw your nomination... I was shocked but your count.

Comment: @bluefeet You have over 1000! That's *quite* respectable indeed!

Comment: Looks like common sock puppetry. That "Agent Smith" most likely is the owner of [that other account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1997113/muhammad-zeeshan) and using it to upvote himself. If he's pulling the strings again we should flag again and have him suspended. [Zee](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1210962/zee) might also be involved, probably friend in real life of the sock puppeteer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Do sock puppets have strings, though? ;-)

Comment: @Andrew lol good point.. well, it sure is smelly! ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber One of these days you will have to explain to me what you're still flagging at your rep level if it's not only "not an answer" stuff.

Comment: @Bart I would say 95% of my flags are split about evenly between *Not an Answer* and *Spam*. I use 'Other' a good bit for some more complex things, or to avoid flagging 200 spam posts from a user, for example.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Damn, so I have to up my game quite a bit. More or less a slow crawl for me by now at 1500 or so flags.

Comment: 9k flags? Jesus I thought my 600 on SF was good.